# How to call functional component from another functionnal component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have to call a functional component from another functional component So how can I call child functional component from a functional component in react js.

```
import React from "react";
import TestFunctional from "./TestFucntional";

const TestListing = props => {
  const { classes, theme } = props;

  const handleClickTestOpen = () => {
    return <TestFunctional />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <EditIcon
        className={classes.icon}
        onClick={handleClickTestOpen}
      />    
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestListing;
```

I am trying to call or render TestFucntional component on EditIcon clicked but it is not called. So How can I call component?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by calling a component. Do you mean a function within the functional component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri. how can you call a function within a functional component from a parent component?

Comment: @Elaine You can make use of useImperativeHandle and ref to expose the child component function to be used in parent. However, a better idea in most cases is to them move the function to parent and pass it on as props to child

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri. thanks for your quick response.  my use case is i have a functional component with d3 tree.  i want to create buttons to expand and collapse all.  if i put it in the functional component the buttons are recreated too many times. So I created the buttons in the parent component render. how do I call the expand and collapse function in the child functional component from the parent?

Answer (score 1):

You just use it in your jsx as a component as usual. You can see [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/jgNEKz)

```js
const ItemComponent = ({item}) => (
<li>{item.name}</li>)

const Component1 = ({list}) => (
<div>
  MainComponent
  <ul>
    {list && list.map(item =><ItemComponent item={item} key={item.id}/>)}
  </ul>
</div>)

const list = [{ id: 1, name: 'aaa'}, { id: 2, name: 'bbb'}]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component1 list={list}/>
  , document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

Comment: Thanks It is working fine to call one component from another component. but If I have to call functional component on button click then How can I call.

Comment: Do you mean to call a function from the parent component?

Comment: No, I have to call or render a child component from a parent component in functional component.

Comment: import React from "react";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import TestFunctional from "./TestFucntional";

const TestListing = props => {
  function handleClickKanbanOpen(testid, testname) {
    return <TestFunctional />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <EditIcon
        onClick={event => {
          handleClickKanbanOpen("1", "test");
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestListing;

I have to call TestFunctional component on edit icon click event.

Comment: add it as code in your question, it is easier to understand

Comment: Do you have to show a component when you click in a button?

Comment: Yes, I have to show a component when clicking on the button.

Comment: I have updated the codepen, I hope it can help you https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/jgNEKz

Answer (score 0):

From the above conversation, I guess you want conditional rendering, i.e. after any event you want to render the child component. To do so in the parent component, it should maintain a state. If you want to use functional parent component, you can use hooks. Or you can use some prop for the conditional rendering as well. Please provide a code snippet.

This is for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html